# using lower_bound or upper_bound on Structure in C++

Tags: c++, struct, lower-bound

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct arr
{
int a;int b;
}a[1000];

bool comp(arr &lhs, arr &rhs)
{  return lhs.a < rhs.a ; }

int main() 
{
    int n,i  ;

    sort(a,a+n,comp);

    int ind= lower_bound(a,a+n,x,comp)-a;

    return 0;
}
```

Error message :

> /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool
>   __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) [with _Iterator = arr*; _Value = const int; _Compare = bool (*)(arr&, arr&)]': /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:965:30:
>
>   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__lower_bound(_ForwardIterator,
>   _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _ForwardIterator = arr*; _Tp = int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val]' /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:2036:46:   required from
>   '_FIter std::lower_bound(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with
>   _FIter = arr*; _Tp = int; _Compare = bool (*)(arr&, arr&)]' prog.cpp:28:38:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/predefined_ops.h:141:37: error: invalid
>   initialization of reference of type 'arr&' from expression of type
>   'const int'   { return bool(_M_comp(*__it, __val)); }
>                                        ^

I wish to use lower_bound over the struct to search for the value x that equals to a[i].a ? I have constructed the comparator function accordingly but getting a long error message of which I am not able to make anything.

What changes are required for the function to run.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did you find out by reading the documentation?

Comment: I read on the web that I have to use lower_bound(a,a+size,x,comp) but its generating error.

Comment: Did you read the error message? Create a [mcve] that reproduces the error.

Comment: I have edit it.

Comment: I doubt the problem is with user input. You can make your example more minimal by getting rid of it.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: Nice :) You're getting close. There is still unnecessary user input for `x`, and you haven't told us the error message.

Comment: Error message provided.

Answer (score 0):

lower_bound returns an iterator, not an index of the element found. You'll need to use std::distance to retrieve the index, but usually, the iterator is what you need/want for further processing.

Also note an index is usually returned as an std::size_t, not an int as you seem to assume.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in previous answers, `lower_bound` returns an iterator.
The type of `x` in `lower_bound` is not clear, `x` should also be the same type as that of the type in the container and compare function.
In this case, the type of `x` should be `arr`.